# (PL SQL) - The answer is always the else statement. No if statement is working

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on         
SET ECHO OFF           
SET VERIFY OFF           
CLEAR SCREEN           

ACCEPT a PROMPT ' Entrez la valeur de a : '          
ACCEPT signe PROMPT ' Entrez la valeur de signe  : '          
ACCEPT b PROMPT ' Entrez la valeur de b  : '          


declare            

signe char(1);             

BEGIN              



if signe = '+' THEN          
     dbms_output.put_line('La valeur de la somme est: ' || &a + &b);              
  elsif (signe = '-') THEN             
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&a - &b);         
  elsif (signe = '*') THEN          
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&a * &b);            
  elsif (signe = '/') THEN          
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&a / &b);           
 ELSE           
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Operation non connue');          
 END if;          
end;          
/
```

I want to take three inputs: A, the math operator and B
The problem is that no if statement seems to work. The code goes directly to the else statement.             Could anyone help me on that?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are several elementary mistakes in your code.

First, you declare a local variable `SIGNE` as `CHAR(1)` in the `DECLARE` section; but you never assign anything to it. So it remains `NULL` throughout execution. This is why you always end up in the `ELSE` section of your `IF` statement.

You are assigning values to **substitution** variables `A`, `SIGNE` and `B`. In the code, you reference `A` and `B` correctly, by preceding them with `&`. But you didn't do the same with `SIGNE`. Note that the variable in the `DECLARE` section is immaterial; it has no relation to the **substitution** variable by the same name.

To fix the code, you can eliminate the `DECLARE` section entirely - it is not needed.

Then, in the `IF` statement - in all branches - you must replace all references to `SIGNE` with `&SIGNE`. Moreover, since the substitution is performed **exactly** as is, if you only do that, you will have checks of the form `+ = '+'`, where the left-hand side is not enclosed in single-quotes. PL/SQL won't understand that. You must put single-quotes around `&SIGNE` everywhere in the code.

Finally, after you do that you will find one more mistake in the code. Concatenation has the same precedence as arithmetic addition. So the hard-coded text will be concatenated with `&A`, and that is followed by an arithmetic addition. You can't add a number to a string (a string which is NOT a number anymore) - so you will get another error. The solution is to use parentheses around the addition (after the concatenation operator).

Comment: Hello Mathguy. I appreciate your attention. It helped me a lot. I got the result correctly and more than that, I understood the reasons as you explained me. Thank you again. It was perfect to me. Have a good day.

Comment: @GuiNogueira - The most important concept from this exercise is the huge difference between substitution variables and pretty much all other kinds of variables (local variables, function parameters, bind variables, etc.) This has to do with "pre-processing", precompiler, macros etc. Essentially a substitution variable is not a variable at all - it's just a shorthand notation in your code, where you provide a substitution string for the shorthand notation, and the precompiler or interpreter (here: SQL\*Plus) performs that substitution for you *before* your code is ever interpreted or compiled.